# CORS failing for POST in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

Setting up CORS for a simple web api in a .NET core app I have this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("GetPolicy",
            builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .WithMethods("GET")
                .WithHeaders("x-mycustomheader-cors"));

        options.AddPolicy("PostPolicy",
            builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .WithMethods("POST")
                .WithHeaders("x-mycustomheader-cors"));
    });

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

I have a get endpoint that's set up like this and works fine:

```
[HttpGet]
[EnableCors("GetPolicy")]
[AuthorizationFilter]
public IEnumerable<MyModel> Get()
{
    //...
}
```

Which works fine, but this (in a different controller):

```
[HttpPost]
[EnableCors("PostPolicy")]
[AuthorizationFilter]
public void Post([FromBody]MyOtherModel[] models)
{
    //...
}
```

Fails with:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

If I change the `PostPolicy` to:

```
options.AddPolicy("PostPolicy",
    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
```

Then POST will work fine cross-domain, but I'd prefer to not just allow anything. So what am I missing here?

Comment: Did you apply this nugget? ["Browsers aren't entirely consistent in how they set Access-Control-Request-Headers. If you set headers to anything other than "*" (or use AllowAnyHeader), you should include at least Accept, Content-Type, and Origin, plus any custom headers that you want to support."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1#preflight-requests)

Comment: @spender - very useful thanks. I'd just come to the conclusion that it was the `Content-Type` that was tripping it up and it appears that it's because I had `Content-Type` set to `application/json` which, according to you link, `Content-Type` only passes automatically if it's `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data` or `text/plain`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimenting a bit, it seemed the `AllowAllHeaders` was the necessary part, so I dug a bit deeper to look at what headers are being passed and strangely, it seems it's the `Content-Type` header that it was tripping up on.

So this worked (from Chrome in a JSFiddle):

```
options.AddPolicy("PostPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .WithMethods("POST")
                .WithHeaders("x-chmura-cors", "Content-Type"));
```

Which is surprising since I would have thought the standard headers (like `Content-Type`) wouldn't need to be explicitly included.

The error message was, of course, completely unhelpful.

**Edit**

So according to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1#preflight-requests (thanks to @spender), the problem is that `Content-Type` only passes automatically if it's value is:

> The Content-Type header, if set, has one of the following values:
>
> - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> - multipart/form-data
> - text/plain

I had mine set to `application/json` and I guess that was what it didn't like.

Comment: Glad to help :)